How to use torch.linalg.eigh?
I'm working on implementing a neural network I saw in a paper as an exercise and there is a small example so Im comparing my solution to that. But I can't seem to get the function to return "correct" eigenVector and eigenValues. These are the expected and my values.
My: Mean: [[0.634 0.316]]^T Covariance Matrix: [[ 0.01238 -0.00733] [-0.00733  0.00753]] Variance: [[0.04726817 0.13295007]] Rotation Matrix: [[-0.58562366 -0.81058308] [-0.81058308  0.58562366]]
Expected: Mean: [[0.634 0.316]]^T Covariance Matrix: [[ 0.01238 -0.00733] [-0.00733  0.00753]] Variance: [[0.4330 0.3473]] Rotation Matrix: [[−0.8106 0.5856] [0.5856 0.8106]]
Here is a minimal version of the code, to get the output:
import torch
import numpy as np

class OEBF_layer():
    def __init__(self, dataSize, v0):
        self.mean = torch.tensor([[0.70, 0.35]], dtype=torch.float64).view(2, 1)
        self.type = torch.tensor([[0, 1]], dtype=torch.float64).view(2, 1)
        self.ptrnCnt = 1
        self.var = torch.full((1, dataSize), v0, dtype=torch.float64)
        self.rot = torch.eye(dataSize, dtype=torch.float64)
        self.cov = torch.eye(dataSize, dtype=torch.float64)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Mean: \n{np.matrix(self.mean.squeeze())}^T\nVariance: \n{np.matrix(self.var)}\nRotation Matrix: \n{np.matrix(self.rot)}\nCovariance Matrix: \n{np.matrix(self.cov)}\nMemberships: {self.type.squeeze().tolist()}^T\nPattern Count: {self.ptrnCnt}"

    def updateCluster(self, x, y):
        newMean = (self.mean * self.ptrnCnt + x) / (self.ptrnCnt + 1)
        self.cov = (self.cov * (self.ptrnCnt - 1) + torch.mm(x, x.t()) + torch.mm(self.mean, self.mean.t()) * self.ptrnCnt - torch.mm(newMean, newMean.t()) * (self.ptrnCnt + 1)) / self.ptrnCnt
        self.mean = newMean
        self.var, self.rot = torch.linalg.eigh(self.cov)
        self.var = torch.sqrt(self.var)
        self.type = (self.type * self.ptrnCnt + y) / (self.ptrnCnt + 1)
        self.ptrnCnt += 1

patterns = torch.tensor([[[[0.58], [0.38]],[[0.49], [0.40]],[[0.78], [0.20]],[[0.62], [0.25]]],[[[0], [1]], [[0], [1]], [[0], [1]], [[0], [1]]]], dtype=torch.float64)

clusters = OEBF_layer(2, 0.3)
for x, y in zip(patterns[0], patterns[1]):
    clusters.updateCluster(x, y)

print(clusters)

I have tried using functions from different libraries, but it always return the same thing. Because of that I suppose I'm just using the function wrong, but nothing in the documentation helped me.

The mentioned paper
Hung-Wen Peng, Shie-Jue Lee, Chie-Hong Lee,
An oblique elliptical basis function network approach for supervised learning applications, Applied Soft Computing, Volume 60, 2017, Pages 552-563, ISSN 1568-4946,
https://doi.org/10.1016/j.asoc.2017.07.019

